# Hiding other rows in a table when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html

```
<table id="linkedin_match">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Industry</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Moses Gonzales</td>
                <td>Greater Seattle Area</td>
                <td>Chemicals</td>
                <td>Superior Grocers</td>
                <td>WC Claim Manager</td>
                <td><a href="#">Invite</a></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="match"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Moses Gonzales</td>
                <td>Greater Seattle Area</td>
                <td>Chemicals</td>
                <td>Superior Grocers</td>
                <td>WC Claim Manager</td>
                <td><a href="#">Invite</a></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="match"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

With the table above, how would I perform the logic, such that if the checkbox is selected, the other rows will hide? The rows are not limited to just two. It could be five, it could be ten, it can be just one. Currently my code is :

```
$('document').ready(function() {
   var tr = $('#linkedin_match tr');
});
```

Now I don't know what to do with the tr. I'm kinda new to JS too. Thanks.

Comment: what is hiding other rows when checkbox is selected? explain?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: I edited the first post. 

@j08691 - How would i set it if maybe it was generated from php?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way. `ids` must be unique so change `match` as class name.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#linkedin_match .match').change(function(){ //bind change event to the checkboxes
        var $this = $(this);
        $('#linkedin_match').find('tr:gt(0)').not($this.closest('tr')).toggle();
        //since all trs are visible you can use toggle to toggle all the trs but not the one that is a parent of this.
       //And un checking will bring all of them back to visible state.
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NdaAx/)**

if you have no control over changing the `id` to class or add a class, then you can target the checkbox

```
 $('#linkedin_match :checkbox').change(function(){...});
```

- [gt(0)](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) - To select the rows with index greater than 0. i.e to avoid the first one.
- [closest('tr')](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - To get the parent tr of the checked element.
- [not($this.closest('tr'))](http://api.jquery.com/not/) - To add a filter. i.e to exclude the current row.
- [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) - To toggle the element's state.

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks2. i change the toggle to fadeToggle to add effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check"> Check me
```

then invoke jquery toggle

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    $('td.hide').toggle();
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webbymatt/DLxjR/**

P.s. in my example I have put a class on the cell I want to hide, this could also be applied to entire rows. In this case:

```
<td class="hide">WC Claim Manager</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will get back on this.

Answer (score 1):

First off you shouldn't have two elements with the same id. change those to classes and you could do the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.match', function(){ 


    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        $('.match').closest('tr').hide();
        $(this).closest('tr').show(); 
    } else { $('.match').closest('tr').show(); }

});
```

This solution will show all rows with a checkbox when a box is unchecked, and only show the relevant row when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Hey thanks sir. Im sorry i can also accept 1 answer, but both of you works.