# Hide record within a table when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide/show records in a table depending on a checkbox checked status

HTML

```
    <label>Add Additional Once off</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkAdditionalOnceoff" onChange="display();"value="0"><br>
    <label>Add Additional Monthly</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkAdditionalMonthly" onChange="display();"value="0">
    <table>
    <div id="AdditionalOnceoff" style="display:none">
    <tr><td><input type="text" id="txtField1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtField2"></td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Normal Record to Display always</td></tr>
    <div id="AdditionalMonthly" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtField3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtField4"></td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function display(){
  if (document.getElementById("chkAdditionalOnceoff").checked) {
   document.getElementById("AdditionalOnceoff").style.display = "inline";
  } else {
   document.getElementById("AdditionalOnceoff").style.display = "none";
  }
   if (document.getElementById("chkAdditionalMonthly").checked) {
   document.getElementById("AdditionalMonthly").style.display = "inline";
  } else {
   document.getElementById("AdditionalMonthly").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

So when the checkbox gets checked the corresponding < div > containing the records should be hide / displayed

I have found this discussion [Hiding other rows in a table when checkbox is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622040/hiding-other-rows-in-a-table-when-checkbox-is-selected)
but cannot find a working example of my scenario.

Comment: This is not even valid HTML ... you can not just put a `div` into a table at this place.

Comment: Use divide and conquer: split the problem into its smallest sub-problems, then tackle each of them individually. All the required information is available here on SO and in the MDN, among other places.

Comment: @CBroe  How else would I identify the section of code to display/hide ?

Comment: @KurtHectic you can just put the id on the <tr> and target the row

Comment: @BenLonsdale because there are multiple rows I want to hide with one checkbox that would obviously not work

Answer (score 0):

hope so you will find solutions from here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
    label{ margin-right: 15px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> red</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
```